# Maven shade plugin Packaging DLL

Tags: java, maven, dll

I have to add to my project a JNI module.

I install the module in Maven as two different artifact: the jar library:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=ssa -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ssa.jar
```

and the runtime library with the DLL

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sirio -Dpackaging=ddl -DartifactId=ssa-runtime -classifier=windows-x86 -Dversion=1.0 -Dfile=SSADll.dll
```

In my maven project I add these dependecies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>ssa</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>ssa-runtime</artifactId>
        <classifier>windows-${arch}</classifier>
        <type>dll</type>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My problem is when I run the shade plugin goal to create a jar with dependencies, I get error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) on project ....: Error creating shaded jar: error in opening zip file sirio\ssa-runtime\1.0\ssa-runtime-1.0-windows-x86.dll
```

How can I tell the shade plugin to do not unpack the dll?

Comment: maven-shade-plugin is intended to shade jar files which are zip like archives and that is what the error shows. Apart from that you can't. You can package your dll into a simple jar file which should solve the problem.

Comment: @khmarbaise it might be useful if you explain how to do that.

Comment: Having the exact same problem as OP, I'd really like to know how to solve this one.

Answer (score 3):

Also being new to Maven, it took me a while to solve a similar problem. This answer may help others.

Using com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc_auth with mssql-jdbc_auth-10.2.3.x64.dll as a dependency.

Fortunately the dll is a separate artifact from the mssql jdbc jar.

To stop the shade plugin trying to open the dll as a zip file....

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.4</version>
      <executions>
      <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <artifactSet>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc_auth</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </artifactSet>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
     </plugin>
```

and then to put the dll into the same directory as the shaded jar file

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy-dependencies</id>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
            <includeArtifactIds>mssql-jdbc_auth</includeArtifactIds>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you need is to package differently. Make the shaded jar with all java classes and libraries you use and then package this jar and the DLL together in a Zip file to be released. For this you can use the `maven-assembly-plugin` with a descriptor for your zip, like this:

In your `pom.xml`:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>zip.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

In `zip.xml` file:

```xml
    <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
        <id>release</id>
        <formats>
            <format>zip</format>
        </formats>
        <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>target</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>myapp.jar</include>
                </includes>
                <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
        <files>
            <file>
                <source>your.dll</source>
                <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
            </file>
        </files>
    </assembly>
```

That way you have all you need to release in this zip. I don't know if that's the best solution, but maybe it solves the problem for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for my JavaFX-OpenCV project

1. package your project without `DLL` files.
2. copy and paste your `DLL` files in the jar file directory.
3. now you can run your application because all `DLL` files are now on the classpath of your jar application.

your directory should be like this :
/target/application.jar
/target/your_DLL_files.dll